How to power on old HP ProLiant ML350 G3 server power supply without motherboard?
I have an old HP ProLiant ML350 G3 server that uses two power supplies and 292235-001 backplane connector. I want to keep the case as a souvenir and use it with a new motherboard.
I have a problem, this power supply backplane works with a 16-pin jack that connects to motherboard for control, I want to modify it to use it to match the new motherboard (24 pin ATX and 8 pin CPU).
Does anyone have a schematic diagram of this 16-pin jack?
Please help me with some information about this power supply backplane
Thank you very much everyone!

For reference this has also been asked on Server Fault How to power on old HP ProLiant ML350 G3 server power supply without motherboard? and the HPE community How to activate old HP ML350 G3 server power supply backplane to use with new mobo. Found the other questions while searching for "292235-001 schematic". Given this is for a 20 year old HP propriety design I doubt the schematic is available online.

Usually, PC power supplies put out a few standard voltages, e.g., 12 V at moderate current, 5 (and possibly 3 V on newer supplies) at high current. Just measure voltage to ground with a small load, since some supplies shut when unloaded. Also, do not put regulated supplies in parallel unless you add very small series resistors in each lead.
